# Associated tables: Join or Include with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, include

I am feeling a bit slow when it comes to rails and the Active Record associations... I have two tables.

Table = **Rings**
Table = **Variations** with foreign_key => "ring_id".

```
class Ring < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :variations
end

class Variation < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :ring
end
```

So in my "index/list" view i want to display all the rings, and both the variations, and i was thinking it would be possible to do this through one SQL query... however, i have tried the join and the include methods and i think i am just not understanding how they work properly.

So my question is, how would i write a query in my controller, that would pull my "title" and "value" column values from the "variations" and combine them into one simple object for easy looping? Or do i have to loop through all rings and look up the variation values during the loop?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@rings = Ring.includes(:variations).all
```

In index.html.erb:

```
@rings.each do |ring|
  ...
  ring.variations.each do |variation|
    ...
  end
end
```

The includes portion of the query will prevent Rails from repeatedly querying the database as you loop through and render your rings and variations in the view.

Comment: Good.  Just note that the ring.variations is the key thing here, as it accesses the data through the association.  The includes is nice to have to improve performance, but the query should still work without it.

Comment: The best thing of all would be to use :delegates to get the variations info to ring but that's a little more advanced (and a better design but not needed).

Comment: So, when i do a <% debug @rings %> on my rings object, it doesn't show the variations as part of the total object. Is there a way to show the entire object to see the combined object?

When I debug it only shows the object before its joined...

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `includes` method: `Ring.inclues(:variations)`. Then the variation will be loaded along with the rings in a single SQL query.

For more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: No you do not *need* to.  It's better performance but that's a little difference.